# Eclipse errors when creating a new android project

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am getting these strange errors when I try to create an Android project in Eclipse (Mars). I tried to uninstall and reinstall both eclipse and the Android SDK but still getting the same error.

Is there some known error with the Android Wear system images in Eclipse?

[image: Error Log]

Comment: Your project isn't finding your styles - what is declared in your Manifest?

Comment: why are you still using eclipse?

Comment: Not at my computer anymore, but I did solve the issue by reducing the target and compile Android version.

Comment: @njzk2 And I'm using eclipse because it works and Android studio is crazy slow. Is there something better out there I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

Just reduced the target sdk and ignored the Android wear all together.